# Authentication by key in Ruby via ssh: Could not parse PKey: no start line

Tags: ruby, ssh, rsa

I'm trying to connect to a server with ssh using an ssh key. The logs me an error and it also asks me for the password which I shouldn't be asked for because I'm using the key authen-ion and my intention is get rid of having to enter the password:

```
 ERROR -- net.ssh.authentication.key_manager[2b02154b7610]: could not load private key file `/home/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub': ArgumentError (Could not parse PKey: no start line)
```

My code:

```
Net::SSH.start(ip_item, "root", host_key: "ssh-rsa", keys: ["~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"], verbose: :debug) do |ssh|
```

Is that a bug? Why does it say "private"?

The key exists.

I'm able to connect to the server via the terminal without a password and it's added to the list of the known hosts of the server properly since I'm able to connect to it.

Also `cat  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server shows my public key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the path to the private key when connecting to a host, not the public key.

Comment: but where in the documentation does it mention that?

Comment: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/net-ssh/net-ssh/Net/SSH says "keys => an array of file names of private keys to use for publickey and hostbased authentication".

Comment: Or you need to ensure ssh-agent is running if there is a password on the key. =\

Answer (score 0):

Try change "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" to "~/.ssh/id_rsa" in your code. It should help.